# Multiplication and derivation of 3D matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, tensors, matrix-calculus

I have $A(q)=\begin{bmatrix}q_1 &q_2 & q_3\\ 2q_1 &3q_2 & 4q_3\\ 2q_1 &3q_1 & 10\\    \end{bmatrix}\tag 1$

$ q= {\left(\begin{array}{c}q_1\\q_2\\q_3\\q_4\\q_5\\q_6 \end{array}\right)}_{6\times1}\tag 2$

I am bit confused with the derivative matrix representation  related to above equations. Could you mention how I can do following operations mention in Question section below.

You can mention the method or procedure of how to do those issues than solving all   the problem step by step.

**For example for  $\frac{\text{d}A(q)}{\text{d}q}$ ,you could mention, the result will be a matrix of dimension $3\times 3\times 6$ of 6, $3\times3$ slices where each slice i is defined by $slice _i=\frac{\text{d}A(q)}{\text{d}q_i}$. Each $slice_i$ tells you to take derivative of that $q_i$ on $A(q)$ elements individually and put back the result in the same location of the matrix**

I am new to these sort of notations that is why I am requesting your help and it is very difficult to find proper martial for complex operations in this regard

**Question**

1. What is the content and matrix representation of $\frac{\text{d}A(q)}{\text{d}q}$ and $\frac{\text{d}^2A(q)}{\text{d}q^2}$? What is the content and matrix representation of $(\frac{\text{d}^2A(q)}{\text{d}q^2})^T$ and $(\frac{\text{d}A(q)}{\text{d}q})^T$?
2. How do we do multiplication of $q^T\frac{\text{d}^2A(q)}{\text{d}q^2}q$ and what will be the resultant matrix and its dimension ? or could you mention the order of multiplication I need to follow on slices
3. If $a.b=b^Ta$ what will be the content of a)$\frac{\text{d}A(q)}{\text{d}q} .\frac{\text{d}A(q)}{\text{d}q} $ b)$\frac{\text{d}A(q)}{\text{d}q} .(q^T\frac{\text{d}^2A(q)}{\text{d}q^2}q )$c)$\frac{\text{d}A(q)}{\text{d}q} .( \frac{\text{d}^2A(q)}{\text{d}q^2}  )$ or could you mention the order of multiplication I need to follow on slices
4. If I have a constant matrix $U_{3\times3}$  then what order should I multiply in order to get a)$U_{3\times3}\frac{\text{d}A(q)}{\text{d}q}$ b)$U_{3\times3}\frac{\text{d}^2A(q)}{\text{d}q^2}$. Bit confused with what row and column order to follow. What will be the resultant matrix and its dimension?
5. What order should I multiply in order to get a)$A(q)_{3\times3}\frac{\text{d}A(q)}{\text{d}q}$ b)$A(q)_{3\times3}\frac{\text{d}^2A(q)}{\text{d}q^2}$ .Bit confused with what row and column order to follow. What will be the resultant matrix and its dimension?

**NB :: Remember here we deal with collection of slices in more than 2D. So it is not as straight as regular 2D case**

Comment: How do you define $q^2$?

Comment: We dont have issue of $q^2$ here. It is not defined.. It is a vector..Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general definition is [Frechet derivatie, or Gateaux derivative if a specific vector unit of differentiation is specified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative). If you applied the definition to the present question, the derivative is a tensor with elements $\Big[\frac{dA(q)}{dq}\Big]_{i,j,k}=\frac{[A(q)]_{i,j}}{dq_k}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix can be written as $A(q) = S\cdot q + B$ where $S$ is a very sparse third order tensor.

$B$ is also sparse, its only non-zero component is $B_{33} = 10$.

The only non-zero components of $S$ are seen by inspection to be 
$$ \eqalign {
 S_{111} &= 1,\,\,\,S_{122} &= 1,\,\,\,S_{133} &= 1 \cr
 S_{211} &= 2,\,\,\,S_{222} &= 3,\,\,\,S_{233} &= 4 \cr
 S_{311} &= 2,\,\,\,S_{321} &= 3 \cr
} $$

Since $A(q)$ is linear, the first derivative is $\frac {\partial A} {\partial q} = S$, which is constant.  So the second, and higher derivatives are zero.